# Problem with AuiMDI frames in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, mdichild

I am creating a AuiMDIParent frame and inside that parent frame I have a AuiMDIChild Frame. Inside the child frame I have a panel which displays an image. My problem is that when I run my code (given below) I get the desired result, but when I try to close the main window that is the parent frame, nothing happens. Then when I close the child frame entire application is closed including parent frame (not just the child frame).

I do not know why is this happening. Please help me figure out if any one has come across such problem. If you run my code you will have a better idea of the problem.

Thanks.

```
import wx
import wx.aui

class ParentFrame(wx.aui.AuiMDIParentFrame):
    '''
        This is main frame
    '''

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        '''
            Creates a Parent Frame which has child frames into it.
        '''
        wx.aui.AuiMDIParentFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,
                                          size=(900,700),
                                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        self.SetMinSize((500,500))
        self.CreateStatusBar()

class NetworkVisualizationFrame(wx.aui.AuiMDIChildFrame):
    '''
        This is a child frame
    '''

    def __init__(self,parent=None,id=-1,title="Network Visualization",image="Default.png"):
        '''
            Creates a child frame inside parent frame.
        '''
        wx.aui.AuiMDIChildFrame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        (frameWidth,frameHeight) = self.GetSizeTuple()

        #=========================================================
        # Create an image panel
        #=========================================================
        imagePanelHeight = int(frameHeight)
        imagePanelWidth = int(0.7 * frameWidth)
        self.imagePanel = wx.Panel(self,id=-1,name="Image Panel",
                                   style=wx.BORDER_THEME,
                                   size=(imagePanelWidth,imagePanelHeight))
                    self.loadImage(image)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onResize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)

    def loadImage(self,image):
        #==================================================
        # Find the aspect ratio of the image
        #==================================================
        self.png = wx.Image(image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        imageHeight = self.png.GetHeight()
        imageWidth = self.png.GetWidth()
        self.aspectRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight
        self.bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.png)

    def onResize(self,event):
        (frameWidth,frameHeight) = self.GetSizeTuple()
        imagePanelWidth = int(0.7 * frameWidth)
        imagePanelHeight = int(frameHeight) 
        self.imagePanel.SetSize((imagePanelWidth,imagePanelHeight))
        (w, h) = self.getBestSize()
        self.imagePanel.SetSize((w,h)) 
        self.scaledPNG = self.png.Scale(w, h)
        self.bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(self.scaledPNG)
        self.Refresh()

    def onPaint(self,event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.imagePanel)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, 0, 0, useMask=False)

    def getBestSize(self):
        (w,h) = self.imagePanel.GetSizeTuple()
        # Keep the height same and change width of the image according to aspect ratio
        newWidth = int (self.aspectRatio * h)
        newSize = (newWidth,h)
        return newSize

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
parentFrame = ParentFrame(None,-1,"Main Frame")
NetworkVisualizationFrame(parentFrame,-1,"Network Visualization","Artifacts_vs_Elaborations_36855.png")
parentFrame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you have the child frame parented to 'None' instead of the mdi parent frame.